# Looking for a diagnostic DVD or CD creation tool

Tags: partition, diagnostic

I am looking for a diagnostic DVD utility (which tests hardware, create partition, fix partition, etc..) which can boot directly when the computer start.

I am looking a solution which support Windows xp and 7 partitions.

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: sysresccd.org, trinityhome.org, ultimatebootcd.com, etc...  Lots of hits when you search for [livecd diagnostic](http://www.google.com/search?q=livecd+diagnostic)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/

Answer (score 1):

My favorite is FalconFour's Ultimate BootCD(http://falconfour.wordpress.com/2011/03/12/falconfours-ultimate-boot-cdusb-4-5/) based on Hiren's BootCD(http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd).

Answer (score 0):

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/